# Store Previous Data in VHDL Process

Tags: signals, vhdl

I have a component where I would like to store the previous data. The current code is as follows:

```
process(data_in)
variable prev_data : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) := "00000000";
begin 

if (prev_data /= "11110000") then

    case(data_in) is 
        when "00011100" =>  
           en <= '1';
           count <= 62500;


        when "00110010" =>      
           en <= '1';
           count <= 50000; 


        when others =>
           en <= '0';
           count <= 0;

    end case;
    else 
        en <= '0';
        count <= 0;
end if;
    prev_data := data_in;
end process;
```

I would like to update prev_data AFTER the comparison has occurred. I have tried setting it to a signal but to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: A variable declared in a process is not available outside the process. A process is comprised of sequential statements executed in order.  What leads you to believe `prev_data` isn't updated after the comparison (evaluation of an expression in the condition of the if statement).  You have no way of telling externally to the process.  Using an event on `data_in` as a latch enable is generally no supported in synthesis either. Show us the waveform display with this exact process that leads to your question.

Comment: I believe I am only using the variable pre_data inside the process no?

If it were updated after the comparison, then I wouldn't be posting here, as the implementation would work.

Re: the synthesis problem. Can you please explain? You might be right. Thanks

Comment: You still haven't demonstrated a problem, under what circumstances it occurs, for what successive values of `data_in` or even how you detect it. Note your code isn't a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

In the future, specify in your question that your problem is synthesis related, among the technology you target and the tool you are using.

As David pointed out, your code describe a latch triggered by a change on any bit of `data_in`. That is not synthesizable by any tool as far as I know. Besides, latches should really not be used.

Any memory element (beside the latch) need a clock signal to operate, the following code would work fine:

```
architecture rtl of some_entity is
    signal prev_data : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
begin

    process(clk)
    begin 

        if rising_edge(clk) then
            prev_data <= data_in;

            if (prev_data /= "11110000") then
                case(data_in) is 
                    when "00011100" =>  
                       en <= '1';
                       count <= 62500;

                    when "00110010" =>      
                       en <= '1';
                       count <= 50000; 

                    when others =>
                       en <= '0';
                       count <= 0;

                end case;
            else 
                en <= '0';
                count <= 0;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

end architecture rtl;
```

You will need to add a clock signal to your entity.

Comment: Thanks, I shall try this!
For future reference: what do you mean by technology you target? (For example: an FPGA?)
Just to clarify: The latch is caused since, during other clock cycles where data_in is not changed, the  signals which I am writing are not assigned?
(That is, it is not clock driven)
Thanks

Comment: By technology, you can be as precise as you want, something like Xilinx, Altera, Lattice, ASIC or Spartan-6, Virtex-7, Cyclone-III, etc. For the latch, in theory yes, but as I mentioned I don't think this syntax is not supported. A latch is generally `process(en, data_in) begin if en = '1' then data <= data_in; end if; end process;`. Don't use latch! If you tell your clock frequency to the tool, it will tell you if it fails to comply, it wouldn't for a latch.

Comment: I see. So in general, it is better to have a clock triggered process due to timing constraints and synthesis rather than processes triggered by some other signal, causing latches. Many thanks! I shall try this code soon and tell you if it works!

Comment: Out of curiosity why did you answer a question asked in a comment "Can you please explain?" here?  Note the actual question does not demonstrate the issue "I would like to update prev_data AFTER the comparison has occurred", nor does your answer address it.

Comment: You are right, the question is unclear, but I thought I understood the issue the asker had.